# Relocation/Cheap Car Hire

Tags: car-rentals

Can anyone recommend any car hire companies that offer cheap car hire for returning their hire cars to another location. I am looking for picking up a hire car from Minneapolis, MN to Jackson Hole, Wyonming. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome. [We don't really do recommendations here on Travel.SE.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help) Moreover, "cheap" is a matter of opinion since what is cheap for you might not be cheap for me. Hence why I am closing this question.

Comment: @Karen Jackson Hole is a very isolated place so I can't imagine car rental companies would be excited about a one-way dropoff there. I think you would have excellent luck buying an old car and selling it in JH, however. There will always be a market for tough, beat up 4WD cars in Jackson Hole; unfortunately these are not often so fuel efficient for a long journey from MN.

Comment: If you're heading there now, before summer, you might try calling the local offices of car rental companies. They may be willing to cut a deal as they may want to add cars for the summer season.